# Hive ALTER TABLE * DROP PARTITION in hive-0.7.1+42.56

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I am trying to drop hive partitions in hive table using following command in hive-0.7.1+42.56

```
ALTER TABLE staging_event DROP PARTITION ( did < 3635 );
```

but i am getting error here

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:58 mismatched input '<' expecting ) near 'did' in drop partition statement
```

If I do

```
ALTER TABLE staging_event DROP PARTITION ( did = 3634 );
```

this works perfectly.

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Comment: Try giving the value in quotes , '3635'

Comment: did < '3635' didn't work

Comment: Inequalities in drop partition statements weren't added until 0.9.0.  See:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2908